# Business quarter end in python

Tags: python, pandas

how do I find the last business day using pandas, please?

I found a solution to m/end, but using this link, I thought Qend would also work but it doesn't

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BMonthEnd
from datetime import date

d=date.today()

offset = BQuarterEnd()
offset2 = BMonthEnd()

#Last day of current month
offset.rollforward(d)



NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-32be55051bf4> in <module>()
      4 d=date.today()
      5 
----> 6 offset = BQuarterEnd()
      7 offset2 = BMonthEnd()
      8 

NameError: name 'BQuarterEnd' is not defined
```

I used this link:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.1/timeseries.html

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: You have not imported BQuarterEnd

Comment: pd.__version__   gives me:
u'0.22.0'

Comment: ahh of course, duh. Thanks both